# Converting BIG numbers (say, 3000 or 100000) to scientific format (say, 10^3 or 3*10^5) in MATHEMATICA

Tags: 3d, wolfram-mathematica, scientific-notation

I have plotted a 3-D plot using Plot3D command. Depending on the parameter values, the plot shows very large numbers (say, 3000 or 100000). So, my z-axis looks very odd as it ocupies large space too. I want to write them in scientific exponential format, say, 3*10^3 or 10^5.

I also see that Mathematica automatically converts the BIG number to scientific format only when the number has seven of more digits. Can anyone help so that I can write any numbers in above-said scientific format?

Comment: Usually URGENT or please reply earliest is not a good way to end a question. Everyone here is helping on his own will and in his own time.

Answer (score 2):

You can define a function for the z-ticks like this :-

```
ticks[min_, max_, n_] := Transpose[Function[z, {z, Function[x,
       ScientificForm[N@x]] /@ z}]@FindDivisions[{min, max}, n]] 

m = 456;

Plot3D[{x^2 + y^2, -x^2 - y^2}, {x, -m, m}, {y, -m, m}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}, 
 Ticks -> {Automatic, Automatic, ticks[#1, #2, 5] &}]
```

[image]

**Edit**

The following can be used to omit the decimal point in the significand of the z-axis ticks :-

```
ticks[min_, max_, n_] := Transpose[Function[z, {z, Function[x,
       ScientificForm[N@x /. (0. -> 0), NumberPoint -> If[IntegerQ[x] &&
           Union[Rest@IntegerDigits@x] == {0}, "", "."]]] /@ z}]@
   FindDivisions[{min, max}, n]]
```

Comment: Really appreciate your reply. It worked for me. Only one thing is how to remove the point mark in the z-axis digits (say, 2.*10^5). How to get rid of this point mark as in the fig? Please reply.  Regards, Samit.

Comment: Thanks a lot.
Let me give you part of the code for you:
    c0 = -0.3;
    k = 1.0; g = 1.2; 
    n = (k - g)/(k + g)^3;
    w3 =(2*n + 2*5^(1/2)*n)^(1/2)-(2*n+2*5^(1/2)*n)^(3/2)/(4*n);
    w4 = (2*n + 2*5^(1/2)*n)^(1/2); 
    lr = Sqrt[w4^2/2];
    z = (\[Xi] - c0*t)/\[Sqrt](1 - c0*c0);
    d = (k - g)/(k + g);
    k00 = -w3/w4;
    c1 = k00/w4;
    u2 = (1 + c0)*d*(some function);

Now, the problem is, at c0=-0.46 it is working fine,but when c0=-0.5, then the numbers on the z-axis are overlapping, making the z-axis clumsy.
How to get neat z-axis for any c0?
Thanks,
Samit.
waiting a reply.

Comment: Sorry, it's fine now. Thanks a lot Chris Degnen. You did a great job for me. God bless!